Split book into several volumes
Sometimes it is not possible to print a book as a single volume because it is too large. This is common with university reprography services, which often limit bound volumes to around 300 sheets (approximately 3 cm thick). Therefore, the goal is to modify an existing document to split it into distinct volumes.
After some research, I found two main strategies for tackling this issue, both using the memoir class. I can either:

Use a single index.tex file that encompasses all volumes.
Use separate index files for each volume and cross-reference them using the xr package.

The first approach seems simpler, but it requires splitting the final PDF afterwards. Key issues to handle are:

Table of contents
Lists of figures, tables, and listings
Index
Glossary
Bibliography

For the table of contents, it should cover both volumes, and the page numbering must reset for each volume. The lists of figures, tables, etc., and the index should also reset per volume, while the glossary and bibliography can be common across volumes.
Related Questions
Several related questions exist on StackExchange, but none fully address the problem, particularly the references (index, glossary, etc.):

Split a book into multiple volumes (2013): This answer does not deal with the references (index, bibliography, glossary). It suggests using a toggle (\newtoggle{volumeone}) and modifying the .toc file, but this approach didn't work for me.
How to use the volumes package (2016): This involves the outdated volumes package, with a comment suggesting the use of xr instead.
Splitting one volume into two (2014): A suggested solution involves the etoc package, but it's more complex than using memoir.
Splitting book into two volumes, each into parts (2016): This doesn't address reference handling.
Splitting a document into two volumes doesn't work (2019): No answers provided.
References in a book split into two volumes (2017): This suggests using xr instead of volumes.

Proposed Solution
Here’s my current approach, though it is not fully functional yet:

The table of contents appears in both volumes, listing the full TOC for each (OK)
Demonstrates a cover page for each volume (OK)
The lists of figures and tables only work partially. They should display figures and tables for the current volume only (FAIL)
The bibliography currently reflects all volumes, though ideally, each volume would have its own bibliography (PARTIALLY OK)
The glossary currently includes terms from both volumes, but I want it to be split by volume (PARTIALLY OK)
The index works, but I using additional complexity (PARTIALLY OK)

LaTeX Code
I am using the following LaTeX code to create the book:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{memoir}
% Necessary packages
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[top=10mm,bottom=10mm]{geometry}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\newcommand\abspagenumber{\inteval{\ReadonlyShipoutCounter+1}}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \newwrite\pagefile
    \immediate\openout\pagefile=\jobname.pages
}

\newcounter{volume}
\newcommand{\newvolume}{%
    \stepcounter{volume}%
    \setcounter{figure}{0}
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
        \immediate\write\pagefile{\abspagenumber}%
    }%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\par\centering \bfseries \large Volume \MakeUppercase{\Numberstring{volume}}\par}
}

\AtEndDocument{%
    \immediate\write\pagefile{\abspagenumber}%
    \immediate\closeout\pagefile
}

\makeglossaries
\makeindex[name=vol1idx,title=Index du Volume 1]
\makeindex[name=vol2idx,title=Index du Volume 2]

\newglossaryentry{glossary2}{%
    name={Foo},
    description={Foo is a term that refers to bar.}}
\newglossaryentry{glossary3}{%
    name={Bar},
    description={Bar is a term that refers to foo.}}

\author{Doc Lathrop Brown}

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom

%% Volume 1
\newvolume
\frontmatter
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagecolor{CadetBlue}
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{5cm}
    {\Huge \bfseries The Book}\\[2cm]
    {\LARGE Volume \MakeUppercase{\Numberstring{volume}}}
\end{center}
\newpage
\nopagecolor

% Table of Contents, Chapters, etc.

\backmatter
\listoffigures\nobreak\nopagebreak
\listoftables\nobreak\nopagebreak
\printglossary
\printindex[vol1idx]
\printbibliography

%% Volume 2
\clearpage
\newvolume
% Volume 2 content similar to Volume 1

\end{document}

PDF Splitting
Once the PDF is generated, I use the index.pages file and pdftk to split the document into different volumes. The index.pages file contains entries like:
1
42
87
115
232

These are converted into page ranges:
1-41
42-86
87-114
115-232

To automate this, I use the following ranges.sh script:
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <index.pages> <input.pdf>"
  exit 1
fi

index_file="$1"
input_pdf="$2"
output_prefix="volume"

lines=($(cat "$index_file"))

num_lines=${#lines[@]}
if [[ $((num_lines % 2)) -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "Error: The index file must contain an odd number of lines."
  exit 1
fi

previous=0
part=1
last_index=$((num_lines - 1))

for i in "${!lines[@]}"; do
  line="${lines[$i]}"

  if [[ $previous -ne 0 ]]; then
    if [[ $i -eq $last_index ]]; then
      range_end=$line
    else
      range_end=$(($line - 1))
    fi

    if [[ $previous -le $range_end ]]; then
      pdftk "$input_pdf" cat "$previous-$range_end" output "${output_prefix}${part}.pdf"
      ((part++))
    fi
  fi
  previous=$line
done

Question
How can I improve this example by solving the following:

Split the index without using two different prefixes
Split the glossary without additional complexity
Reset list of figures/tables between each volumes
Simplify the overall complexity

Preview









There are two ways to look at this. That each volume is self-contained, has its own contents, index and glossary, in which case each volume is a different book! Or they form a continuum, common TOC, index, glossary etc. Both methods will work very well, with hyperlinks for electronic documents. For printing the service will have to print from the pdf from pages 1..300, 301..etc. I think it is very important for the electronic document to have all cross-references right and clickable. Multiple indexes I would recommend to only use, if it makes sense, splitting them by topic rather than volum.

Check this book which is one of 5 in a series  https://www.cambridge.org/qa/universitypress/subjects/languages-linguistics/asian-language-and-linguistics/ancient-languages-asia-minor?format=PB&isbn=9780521684965  if is available in your library or a freedom service... It has some very good ideas of how to split.
